# Drawing lines in part of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Drawing in a UIView works but it uses the entire screen. I have a UIViewController with a lot of text and results being displayed. I want to add draw some lines showing the tilt and roll angle of a a ship.I could do this with some `CGAffineTransform rotate` but would prefer not to.

What I have not worked out is how to implement CG components in a UIViewController where it is only addressing part of the screen.

Is this allowed?

Comment: Couldn't you do the drawing in a small subview that you add to the main view?

Comment: Suspected that was the answer, just wondering if there were other approaches that could be used - many thanks.